# check if all textboxes have values

Tags: angularjs, validation, ionic-framework

newbie here.. i'm trying to get all the input values of my textboxes in a single button click. currently it works fine, but when i added a validation code to see if there are no empty textboxes it doesnt go to the next page even if the textboxes are not empty. am i missing something?

here's my controller.js code:

```
.controller('register1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 
'fnameProperty', 'mnameProperty', 'lnameProperty',
'bdayProperty', 'emailProperty',
function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, fnameProperty, mnameProperty, 
lnameProperty, bdayProperty, emailProperty) 
{


    $scope.goNextandSave = function(fname,mname,lname,bday,email)
    {
      if ($scope.fname != null && $scope.fname != "" 
      && $scope.mname !=null && $scope.mname !=""
      && $scope.lname !=null && $scope.lname !=""
      && $scope.bday !=null && $scope.bday !=""
      && $scope.email !=null && $scope.email !="") 
      {
          //do something
         fnameProperty.setProperty(fname);
         mnameProperty.setProperty(mname);
        lnameProperty.setProperty(lname);
        bdayProperty.setProperty(bday);
        emailProperty.setProperty(email);

        $state.go('register2'); 
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Please complete the form.');
      }

    }

 ])
```

and here's a sample textbox html code:

```
  <label class="item item-input" id="register1-input1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="fname">
  </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach chosen should be a little different according to me.

In your `<form>`, add `ng-init="obj={}"`.

Then in each of your text boxes, add `ng-model="obj.fname"`, `ng-model="obj.mname"` and so on.

Call your submit function by `ng-submit` in form tag.

**Use `required` to see if all textboxes have values.**
and other html5 form validations can also be used for client side validation.

If you want your own validation function, you can use angular validations or you can even call the validation in you submit function in controller.

Now, the submit function shall be called as `ng-submit="mySubmitFunction(obj)"`. This will pass your whole object of textboxes in form to your controller submit function in the form of JSON object. Hence you wont have to use so many scope variables.

Now if you are looking forward to submit the data to server, you can pass this object that you will receive in your controller function directly to the factory and then to server through an `$http` request.

This is the best practice to do it.

------------------------UPDATE-------------------------

Here is the implementation of getting form data to controller.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.doSubmit = function(x) {
    console.log("Submitted Data", x);
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form ng-init="obj = {}" ng-submit="doSubmit(obj)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.mname" placeholder="Middle Name" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the input. i've tried required to check if all textboxes have values, however it's not working.

Comment: I have implemented the thing I have explained and also used `required` @SydnieS Do comment here and tell if its not working.